# Wrap content in Circle LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I want wrap content in Circle LinearLayout. Please check attachment.
and here's my XML code: 
 here's my code...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Dew Point: " />

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="8.7c, " />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: do you have that background image?

Comment: no, i'm use Linear-layout.

Comment: thats an image so you will need that, as background i can give you generic directions

Answer (score 0):

**1.** **you can follow this. you can adjust the ImageView gravity as Left, center or right.**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/your_photo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dew Point: " />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8.7c, " />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This will help you to get a result like this.

[image]

**2. you can also follow this. To get big Image view.**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/your_photo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dew Point: " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8.7c, " />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Result:

[image: result]